# Get the coordinate of two elements by its class and drag the first coordinate to the second coordinate in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to get the coordinate of two elements by its class and drag the first coordinate to the second coordinate in Selenium.
This is my code.

```
an_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("randomstuff1")
another_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("randomstuff2")
# Get coordinate of an_element.
# Get coordinate of another_element.

#drag the coordinate of an_element to the coordinate of another_element.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop(an_element, another_element).perform()
```

Did you want to drag and drop an element to the second element?

Comment: How to change speed of the drag?